# Execute 20,000 BAT files with one command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Let's say I have 20,000 BAT files, and I want to execute them all in one shot. But instead of typing line after line: 
"Start/Call file1.bat...." 
"Start/Call file2.bat...."
"Start/Call file3.bat...."

Is there a quicker way I can execute all 20,000 bat files with one command? If you wanted to execute all files in a folder in Linux, you would use the command:
./(path)/*

Comment: Consider using a pause or some sort of delay too if you have load issues on the machine running the 20k scripted processes.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Is there a system out there that won't fall over with 20,000 jobs starting all at once?  That's an awful lot of memory that will be demanded.

Comment: The OP did not say they should start all at once - he said with one command.  I imagine he would want them to run consecutively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `./(path)/*` won't work on Linux, either -- it will just run the first one and pass the rest of them as parameters to it. You need to use a loop.

On Linux that would be, e.g.:

```
for i in path/* ; do $i ; done
```

The equivalent on Windows batch is, if you run it on the commandline:

```
for %i in (path\*) do @call %i
```

Or if you put it inside a batch file:

```
for %%i in (path\*) do @call %%i
```

You will run into issues with the length of the command if you have 20,000 files, so you might need a different scheme for iterating over them. If they are all numbered sequentially, you could just iterate the numbers.

Comment: Using `call` or `start` tho for Windows batch scripts and maybe consider using some variable substitutions specifying the full path and batch script file names explicitly and double quoted.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph about "length of the command". Not sure what you mean. If you mean time to execute 20,000 files, yes that is a concern, but iterating numbers wouldn't make it any faster. If you mean the number of bytes in the command line, then no, that is not an issue.

Comment: @dbenham On Linux (bash) there is a limit to the length, as the file names are actually expanded into the command, but yes, on Windows it behaves differently.